# Access VBA - Runtime error in Update Macro

Tags: vba

I'm fairly new to vba (and to this website - so apologies if I post this incorrectly), previously a SQL developer, but unfortunately my new job involves working in access 2010 only. I'm trying to build a vba macro which will run various update statements. I have built the queries in access and I'm trying to call the query in vba. I have tried doing this with one access query and I'm running into a run time error - syntax error in UPDATE statement. The query runs fine in access but the vba function fails with the runtime error.

The following is my vba function:

```
Public Function TestUpdate1()
Dim cmdT As ADODB.Command
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim prmT As ADODB.Parameter

Set cnn = Application.CurrentProject.Connection
Set cmdT = New ADODB.Command
Set cmdT.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmdT.CommandText = "Update Table 1"
cmdT.CommandType = adCmdText

'Set prmT = cmdT.Parameters("Acc_Date")
'prmT.Value = #12/31/2012#
cmdT.Execute

'Set cmdT = Nothing
'
'If Err <> 0 Then
' cmdT.ActiveConnection.RollbackTrans
'Else
' cmdT.ActiveConnection.CommitTrans
'End If
End Function
```

When I debug the function the error occurs on line cmdt.Execute.

The sql query (Update Table 1) it is executing is as follows:

```
UPDATE Table_1 SET Product = IIf(Contract Like "*budget*amt*","BUDGET Annual",
IIf(Contract Like "*CLASSIC*AMT*","CLASSIC Annual",
IIf(Contract Like "*essential*AMT*","ESSENTIAL Annual",
IIf(Contract Like "*P*PLUS*AMT*","Premier Plus Annual",
IIf(Contract Like "*SELECT*AMT*","SELECT Annual",
IIf(Contract Like "*prestige*AMT*","PRESTIGE Annual",
IIf(Contract Like "*GAP*","GAP Productl",
IIf(Contract Like "*SINGLE*TRIP*","SINGLE TRIP",
IIf(Contract Like "*premier*","PREMIER Annual",
IIf(Contract Like "*standard*","STANDARD Annual",
IIf(Contract Like "*EVAC*","European VAC","???"))))))))))), End_Date =  Depart_Date+Days;
```

Any help you can give on the above would be gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

this code is trying to execute the SQL statement: *Update Table 1*

```
cmdT.CommandText = "Update Table 1"
cmdT.CommandType = adCmdText
cmdT.Execute
```

to execute a **query** named *Update Table 1*, you need this code:

```
Docmd.OpenQuery "Update Table 1"
```

if you don't want warnings about the number of rows that are about to be updated,

```
With DoCmd
     .SetWarnings False
     .OpenQuery "Update Table 1"
     .SetWarnings True
End With
```

This is code I use to run a parametrized query using an access project and ADODB

```
Dim cmdl As ADODB.Command
Dim StrCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsRecSet As New ADODB.Recordset

StrCon.Open CurrentProject.Connection

'Set CONNECTION timeout property
StrCon.CommandTimeout = 0

'Create a new command object to process the stored proc
Set cmdl = New ADODB.Command

With cmdl
    .ActiveConnection = StrCon
    'set COMMAND timeout property - query can time out on either the connection OR the command
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .CommandText = "spCrossTabRun"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters(1).value = "MyValue1"
    .Parameters(2).value = "MyValue2"
    .Parameters(3).value = "MyValue3"
    Set rsRecSet = .Execute()
End With
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for responding. I was going to go down the DoCmd route, however this is the first of several updates. One of my other updates has parameters, so I decided to use ADODB instead, as I was unsure if you could pass parameters with DoCmd. Can you execute Access queries using ADODB or is it SQL server only? Sorry but as I mentioned only a beginner with VBA

Comment: @GraemeWilson, Added an example of ADODB. With an Access Project (which is what I am assuming with an ADODB connection), you cannot store any queries in the database itself. All views and procedures will be on the SQL server

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of centralized functions to return read-only or read/write access to an adodb recordset. Like:

```
Public Function dbWrite(SQLQuery As String, Optional blDynamic As Boolean) As ADODB.Recordset
'Centralized function to read data from db, return a EDITABLE recordset
Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset

If blDynamic = True Then
    r.Open SQLQuery, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, dbSQLPassThrough
Else
    r.Open SQLQuery, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic, dbSQLPassThrough
End If

Set dbWrite = r

Exit Function
End function
```

so to call it, within a new function:

```
Public Function SomeFunction
Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim s As String
set r = dbwrite("SELECT * FROM TABLE;")
s = "My Parameterized Value"
r.AddNew
     r![Fieldname] = s
     r.Update
r.Close
set r = nothing
End function
```

Having the dbWrite function makes things easy, and parsing out the fieldnames one at a time makes it easy to call another function, a simple IF, or whatnot.